# XCode 4.5 app file start installer, not the program?

Tags: xcode, installation

I am trying to get Xcode 4.5 running along side my current XCode version.

I can see alot of posts saying you just drag the .app file from the dmg to a place on your HD, but when I do that and tries to start XCode 4.5 from that file it starts an installer.

From what I have read it should simply start the program right away. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Downloaded the dmg file from iOS Dev Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it fine. The first-launch installer installs a couple things required for the new version (e.g. Libraries for talking to newly-supported hardware), but it won't interfere with the workings of the previous version of Xcode. The same thing happened with Xcode 4.4 and 4.3.